# Monitoring/debugging memory usage C

Tags: c, memory-management

I have an issue with my program using much more memory than I think it should

I've used valgrind and it has been a godsend for discovering memory problems such as buffer overruns and memory leaks

Problem I have here is that it doesn't look like its a leak, just usage that is inconsistent with what I think it should be

Is there another tool that you can use to monitor memory usage in the same way you might monitor variable values using a debugger such as gdb?

massif has told me that the lion share of the heap memory is being allocated via this statement:

```
->98.80% (1,338,700,288B) 0x40341D5: caa (caa.c:196)
```

the statement being a call to push an element on to a UT_array, e.g.

```
utarray_push_back(utarr_ctr_pdws, &pdw);
```

pdw is a pointer to a struct and is a stack variable

So it would seem the memory that UT_array is mallocing isn't getting freed, but I have another statement a few lines down explicitly doing this:

```
utarray_free(utarr_ctr_pdws);
```

The UT_array is just an array of pointers therefore doesn't need any additional dtor function defined in the UT_ICD helper struct.

If anyone has any experience of using UT_arrays maybe you can shed some light on why its using up so much memory?

Comment: You could try massif, a valgrind tool to show heap allocations. Even if you don't strictly have a leak (you still keep a pointer to allocated memory) it will show you where you are allocating large amounts of memory.

Comment: looks good - just experimenting with it now...

Comment: In my experience, if valgrind shows an error, there is a problem. My you could post the problematic code?

Comment: @eyalm - i've analysed the valgrind memcheck output and theres nothing by way of leaks that looks anywhere near serious enough to explain what I'm seeing on system monitor (memory usage) so currently having a look at valgrind massif - 1st imressions are that its exactly waht i need in this instance. its more a case of finding the problem as opposed to fixing the problem at this stage!

Comment: @BoBTFish - happy to accept your comment as an answer as it looks like a very good solution to my problem.

Comment: What platform is this running on? Linux? What are you using to measure memory usage? 'top'?

Comment: yes linux, i'd forgotten about top - i was using system monitor - top would be better - but system monitor did highlight my laptop was running out of memory pretty quickly. Massif has enabled me to see that the problem is in allocating heap mmory for UT_arrays (I'm using this data structure - http://uthash.sourceforge.net/utarray.html) . They don;t seem to be getting freed...

Comment: just figured out how to run top from within emacs - use M-x term top, not M-x shell top

Comment: have fixed the problem - utarray was being freed within an if statement whereas it was being created outside of the if statement therefore a bunch of arrays were being created but not freed, sounds like a classic memory leak but valgrind memcheck didn't pick it up - not sure why, possibly because utarray is implemented in macros?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

valgrind massif is the answer here, its a heap memory analysis tool (see http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/ms-manual.html)

Answer (score 1):

I suspect there's something in your pdw struct that you've allocated space for. `utarray_free` won't know about the members of the struct, so it'll only free the pointer to the struct itself. If you've malloc'd space for any member of the struct, `utarray_free` won't know how to clear them unless you set a dtor function in your `UT_icd` to free alloc'd struct members.